# I'm not able to render an object property that's inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access the array values of this without much luck. I'm trying to access the label inside food. I've tried it doing this `{data.parsed[0].label}` but I'm getting an error `0` of undefined whenever I try this. Why can that be if that's how you access an object?

```
{
    "text":"apple"
    "parsed":[
    0:{
    "food":{
    "foodId":"food_a1gb9ubb72c7snbuxr3weagwv0dd"
    "uri":"http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Food_apple"
    "label":"Apple"
    "nutrients":{...}
    "category":"Generic foods"
    "categoryLabel":"food"
    "image":"https://www.edamam.com/food-img/42c/42c006401027d35add93113548eeaae6.jpg"
    }
    }
    ]
    "hints":[...]
    "_links":{
    "next":{...}
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, is it the console.log?

Comment: it is a test endpoint from rapidAPI

Comment: Can you please use console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) and share the result, since this is not the valid JSON?

Comment: But it is still not valid JSON to access it by javascript. could you please share the console logged object?

Comment: Array elements are number, boolean, string, array, or object. `0: { ... }` is not any one of those.

Comment: ```"parsed": [ 0: { } ] ``` is not a valid array

Comment: ```{text: "apple", parsed: Array(1), hints: Array(22), _links: {…}}
hints: (22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
parsed: Array(1)
0:
food:
category: "Generic foods"
categoryLabel: "food"
foodId: "food_a1gb9ubb72c7snbuxr3weagwv0dd"
image: "https://www.edamam.com/food-img/42c/42c006401027d35add93113548eeaae6.jpg"
label: "Apple"
nutrients: {ENERC_KCAL: 52, PROCNT: 0.26, FAT: 0.17, CHOCDF: 13.81, FIBTG: 2.4}
uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#Food_apple"```

This is the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the component is trying to render before the data is available. Try adding a check to ensure that the data is available:

```
{data && data.parsed && data.parsed[0] && data.parsed[0].label}
```

...or if you can use optional chaining:

```
{data?.parsed?.[0]?.label}
```